# Gnuplot, Text on y-axis and values inside the chart area

Tags: plot, gnuplot

It is easy to plot X-Y data points like this

```
# X   Y
  1   2
  2   4
  4   1
  ...
```

with Gnuplot.

However I am trying to plot data points like this

```
# Model     2010 2011 2012 2013
  M1              10        15
  M2         5    20  
  M3         10   10   20
```

The chart has texts on Y-axis

```
   ^
   |
 M1|          10           15
 M2|     5    20
 M3|     10   10    20
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+----->
      2010  2011   2012   2013
```

How can I do that?

```
set xtics ("2010" 0, "2011" 1, "2012" 2, "2013" 3)
set ytics ("M1" 0, "M2" 1, "M3" 2)
plot 'data.txt' ??????
```

Comment: Yes, you can set tics like that - have you tried it and it didn't work? Please clarify.

Comment: I don't know what I put in front of `plot`. What is the correct usage of `using` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on [this suggestion how to mirror Matlab's `spy` function](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/f5cUKA-13ck).
However, you'll have to reformat your data file to look like this (saved as `data.dat`):

```
NaN  10   NaN  15  
5    20   NaN  NaN  
10   10   20   NaN
```

This will help distinguish between the elements that should be plotted (the numbers) and those that should not appear (`NaN`).

Here's the code which will produce the plot you sketched in your question:

```
# the code will plot the numbers as labels:
set style data labels

# set up x- and y-coordinates based on the rows and columns
xcoord(N) = (N) 
ycoord(N) = (column(0)+1)

# define a symbol to be used as label:
# every NaN will be empty (" "), 
# and everything not equal to NaN (ne), will be a string 
# of the actual element
symbol(N) = strcol(N) ne "NaN" ? strcol(N) : " "

# define the ranges, use reverse with the yrange
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:4] reverse

# set the tics (this is something you already had)
set xtics ("2010" 1, "2011" 2, "2012" 3, "2013" 4)
set ytics ("M1" 1, "M2" 2, "M3" 3)

# the actual plot command
# N will count through the number of columns

plot for [N=1:4] 'data.dat' using (xcoord(N)):(ycoord(N)):(symbol(N)) w labels
```

The plot you will get looks like this:

[image: plot-demo]

Comment: Yeah it fully works. I have modified to add more data points and it is perfect. Thanks